# ExtJs 3.4 trigger on download

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

In my application, I have to `block` the user interaction while the server creates an Excel file to download and 'unblock' it once the file is available to download.

> **CODE SNIPPET**

```
...
myGrid.setDisabled(true);
Ext.getBody().mask("myMessage");
...

Ext.Ajax.request({
   url :  myUrl,
   method : 'POST',
   form: Ext.fly('frmDummy'),
   isUpload: true,
   callback: function() {                                                       
     myGrid.setDisabled(false);
     Ext.getBody().unmask();
   } 
});
```

The problem is that it does not enter the callback function.If I set the property `isUpload: false` the callback function works but the application does not download the file.

My objective is to `unblock` the grid once the file is ready to download. I'm open to other alternatives.

---

PS: I have read that an Ajax request is not the best choice to download a file but this is not my code and it is used as an standard in the application.

Comment: I know that this thread is old, but have you solved your problem?

Comment: Hmm, take into account that i had that problem long ago... if i remember correctly i could not access the magicform callback but i could access the json created in backend, i added an attribute in the json that i would later assign in backend, therefore i was using an onChangeHandler on such attribute, hope it helps!